# Cross-Validated Metrics for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In an attempt to get some practice using Python, I have assigned myself a number of machine learning statistical tasks. Currently, I am struggling with coding cross-validation for logistic regression.

Here is some code that produces the synthetic dataset I am working on:

```
#### Create synthetic data

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.stats import bernoulli 
from sklearn import preprocessing

customerID, sex, age, salary, happiness = [], [], [], [], []

random.seed(45)

for i in range(0,60):
    customerID.append(i+1)
    age.append(random.randint(18,65))
    salary.append(random.randint(1200,3600))
    if i%2==0:
     sex.append('M')
    else:
     sex.append('F')
    if salary[i]>=120*age[i] and sex[i]=='M':
       p = 0.75
    elif salary[i]>=120*age[i] and sex[i]=='F':
       p = 0.7
    elif salary[i]<=70*age[i] and sex[i]=='M':
       p = 0.4
    elif salary[i]<=70*age[i] and sex[i]=='F':
       p = 0.5
    else:
       p = 0.58
    happiness.append(-1+bernoulli.rvs(p,1))

### Create dataFrame now

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(customerID,sex,age,salary,happiness)), 
               columns =['customerID','sex','age','salary','happiness']) 
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for column_name in df.columns:
        if df[column_name].dtype == object:
            df[column_name] = le.fit_transform(df[column_name])
        else:
            pass

df.head()
# Divide the data into dependent variable and independent variables
X = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]])
y = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,[4]])
```

Here is the code that produces an 'IndexError: too many indices for array':

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics, cross_validation

from sklearn import metrics, cross_validation
logreg=LogisticRegression()
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(logreg, X, y, cv=10)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y, predicted))
print(metrics.classification_report(y, predicted))
```

How would you go about solving this problem?

Comment: what is `X.shape` and `y.shape`,  could you add `x.head()` and `y.head()` looks likes these are creating the error somehow

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that replacing

```
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(logreg, X, y, cv=10)
```

with

```
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(logreg, X, y.values.ravel(), cv=10)
```

works fine.

Comment: Thanks, mate! Nothing stimulates memory as much as a nagging error.